# Simple pop-up modal onclick display youtube video simple DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Simple pop-up link click me](http://jsbin.com/vudiba/edit?html,output)

If I replace `<img src="http://deskbg.com/s3/wpp/26/26833/ferocious-tiger-desktop-background.jpg" width="100%" />` with `<iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0mQLTWvXbXM" 
</iframe>`

It does not work. I dont want this with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing `>` on `<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0mQLTWvXbXM" 
</iframe>`

`<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0mQLTWvXbXM"></iframe>`